# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to get all records in list view from sqlite database but getting exception of  **IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.** again and again . If I remove   **db.close();** even then getting same issue . How to resolve this issue.

Here is my code in db helper class.

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ClassNKK.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private Context context;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    String str_Authentication_Token;
    String str_LoginUserId;
    String str_UserName;
    String str_UserRole;


    public MyDbHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {.....}


@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_COMPANY);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_VesselList);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Inspector_List);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_AllPost_Table);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_ActivityObjectList);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_FollowUpList);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_SyncTime);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_VEsselHashTag);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_FollowUpSettings);

        onCreate(db);


    public boolean update_AllPost(String strActivityStatus, String strActivityId,
                                  String strRemark,
                                  String strName,
                                  String strInspectorName,
                                  String strShortname,
                                  String strHashTag,
                                  String strStatus,
                                  String strType,
                                  String strUserId,
                                  String strObjectId,

                                  String strActiondate,
                                  String strStarFlag,
                                  String strDownLoadStatus,
                                  String strUpLoadStatus,
                                  String strStarMarkUpLoadStatus,
                                  String strUpLoad_FollowUpStatus,
                                  String strUpLoad_UnFollowUpStatus )
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COL_AllPost_ActivityStatus, strActivityStatus);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_PostActivityId, strActivityId);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_Remark, strRemark);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_Title, strName);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_inspectorname, strInspectorName);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_shortName, strShortname);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_HashTag, strHashTag);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_Status, strStatus);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_Type, strType);

        args.put(COL_AllPost_UserId, strUserId);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_VesselId, strObjectId);

        args.put(COL_AllPost_ActionDate, strActiondate);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_StarFlag, strStarFlag);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_DownLoadStatus, strDownLoadStatus);
        args.put(COL_ALLPOST_UpLoad_Status , strUpLoadStatus);
        args.put(COL_ALLPOST_UpLoad_StarMark_Status ,strStarMarkUpLoadStatus);
        args.put(COL_ALLPOST_UpLoad_FollowUpStatus ,strUpLoad_FollowUpStatus);
        args.put(COL_ALLPOST_UpLoad_UnFollowUpStatus ,strUpLoad_UnFollowUpStatus);

        int i = db1.update(Table_AllPost_Table, args, COL_AllPost_PostActivityId + "=" + strActivityId, null);

        return i > 0;

    }




    public boolean update_FollowUpPost(String Followup,
                                       String FollowupType,
                                       String activityId,
                                       String createdBy,
                                       String date,
                                       String editableFlag,
                                       String follow_id,
                                       int followupId,
                                       String objectId,
                                       String followUp_UpLoadStatus
                                      )
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COL_Followup, Followup);
        args.put(COL_FollowupType , FollowupType);
        args.put(COL_Followup_activityId, activityId);
        args.put(COL_Followup_createdBy, createdBy);
        args.put(COL_Followup_date, date);
        args.put(COL_Followup_editableFlag, editableFlag);
        args.put(COL_FID, follow_id);
        args.put(COL_followupId, followupId);
        args.put(COL_Followup_objectId, objectId);
        args.put(COL_FollowUp_UpLoadStatus , followUp_UpLoadStatus);

        int i = db1.update(Table_FollowUpList, args, COL_followupId + "=" + followupId, null);

        return i > 0;

    }

    }

 public boolean isAllPostId_Exist(String activityId) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_AllPost_Table, new String[]{COL_AllPost_PostActivityId}, COL_AllPost_PostActivityId + "=?",

                new String[]{String.valueOf(activityId)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return false;

            } else {
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isConpany_IdExit(String strCompanyId) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_COMPANY, new String[]{COL_Company_Id}, COL_Company_Id + "=?",

                new String[]{String.valueOf(strCompanyId)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                //   Log.e("Row is  Not  ", " Exist in Table_VesselList Table in MyDbHelper");

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return false;

            } else {

                //  Log.e("Row is   already ", " Exist in Table_VesselList Table in MyDbHelper ");
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isActivityObject_ImageAudioPath(String str_ImageAudioPath) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_ActivityObjectList, new String[]{COL_imageaudioPath}, COL_imageaudioPath + "=?",

                new String[]{String.valueOf(str_ImageAudioPath)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return false;

            } else {


                cursor.close();
                 db.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isExistNotation(String str_Notation) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_VEsselHashTag, new String[]{VesselHashTag}, VesselHashTag + "=?",

                new String[]{String.valueOf(str_Notation)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                //Log.e("Row is Not  ", " Exist in ActivityObjectList Table in MyDbHelper");
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return false;

            } else {

                //Log.e("Row is already ", " Exist in ActivityObjectList Table in MyDbHelper ");
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

 public void insertCompany(String strCompanyId, String strCompanyName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_Company_Id, strCompanyId);
        values.put(COL_CompanyName, strCompanyName);
        db1.insert(Table_COMPANY, null, values);
        db1.close();
    }

    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
            super.close();
        }
    }

    /********************************************************************************************************/

    public boolean updateStarFlag(String str_ActivityId, String str_StarFlag, String str_StarMark_UpLoadStatus) {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COL_AllPost_PostActivityId, str_ActivityId);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_StarFlag, str_StarFlag);
        args.put(COL_ALLPOST_UpLoad_StarMark_Status, str_StarMark_UpLoadStatus);

        int i = db1.update(Table_AllPost_Table, args, COL_AllPost_PostActivityId + "= ? ", new String[]{str_ActivityId});

        return i > 0;
    }

    public void insert_VesselList(String strACtiveStatus, String strVessCompanyId, String strVesselName, String strVesseleId, String strVesselsTypeId, String VesselsTypeName, String strClassCodeNumber, String strIsFollowedVessels) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_ACtiveStatus, strACtiveStatus);
        values.put(COL_VessCompanyId, strVessCompanyId);
        values.put(COL_VesselName, strVesselName);
        values.put(COL_VesseleId, strVesseleId);
        values.put(COL_VesselsTypeId, strVesselsTypeId);
        values.put(COL_VesselsTypeName, VesselsTypeName);
        values.put(COL_ClassCodeNumber, strClassCodeNumber);
        values.put(COL_IsFollowedVessels, strIsFollowedVessels);

        db.insert(Table_VesselList, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean isUserDetails_Exist(String strUserName) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_NAME, new String[]{COL_Username}, COL_Username + "=?",

                new String[]{String.valueOf(strUserName)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                // Log.e("Row is  Not  ", " Exist in Table_VesselList Table in MyDbHelper");

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return false;

            } else {

                //  Log.e("Row is   already ", " Exist in Table_VesselList Table in MyDbHelper ");
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
 public List<All_Post> getMyAll_StarPost(int OFFSET) {
    List<All_Post> allPostDescList = new ArrayList<All_Post>();
    String selectQuery = "select * from  " + Table_AllPost_Table + " where StarFlag='1' AND ActiveStatus = '1' AND Status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY ActionDate DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET "+OFFSET ; // LIMIT 50 OFFSET "+OFFSET;

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            All_Post allPostDesc = new All_Post();
            allPostDesc.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ALL_ACT_ID")));
            allPostDesc.setStrActiveStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActiveStatus")));
            allPostDesc.setStrActivityId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActivityId")));
            allPostDesc.setStrRemark(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Remark")));
            allPostDesc.setStrProfilePic(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProfilePICURL")));
            allPostDesc.setStringInspectorname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("inspectorName")));
            allPostDesc.setStrNotationNo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("HashTag")));
            allPostDesc.setStrUserId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UserId")));
            allPostDesc.setStrvessel_Id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VesselId")));
            String strSqliteDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActionDate"));
            allPostDesc.setStrStarFlag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StarFlag")));
            allPostDesc.setStrDownLoadStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status")));

            if (strSqliteDate != null && !strSqliteDate.isEmpty()) {
                String result = "";
                Date date1 = null;
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                try {
                    date1 = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date1);
                SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                result = printFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                //Log.e("result = ","==========>"+result);
                allPostDesc.setActiondate(result);
            }


            allPostDescList.add(allPostDesc);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        db.close();

    }
    return allPostDescList;
}

public List<All_Post> getMyAllPost(String strUserId , int OFFSET) {
    List<All_Post> allPostDescList = new ArrayList<All_Post>();
    String selectQuery = "select * from  " + Table_AllPost_Table + " where  UserId=" + strUserId + " AND ActiveStatus = '1' AND Status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY ActionDate DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET "+OFFSET;

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            All_Post allPostDesc = new All_Post();
            allPostDesc.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ALL_ACT_ID")));
            allPostDesc.setStrActiveStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActiveStatus")));
            allPostDesc.setStrActivityId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActivityId")));
            allPostDesc.setStrRemark(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Remark")));
            allPostDesc.setStrProfilePic(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProfilePICURL")));
            allPostDesc.setStringInspectorname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("inspectorName")));
            allPostDesc.setStrNotationNo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("HashTag")));
            allPostDesc.setStrUserId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UserId")));
            allPostDesc.setStrvessel_Id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VesselId")));
            String strSqliteDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActionDate"));
            allPostDesc.setStrStarFlag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StarFlag")));
            allPostDesc.setStrDownLoadStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status")));


            if (strSqliteDate != null && !strSqliteDate.isEmpty()) {
                String result = "";
                Date date1 = null;
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                try {
                    date1 = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date1);
                SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                result = printFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                //Log.e("result = ","==========>"+result);
                allPostDesc.setActiondate(result);
            }

            allPostDescList.add(allPostDesc);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        db.close();

    }
    return allPostDescList;
}

public List<All_Post> getAllDescriptions(int OFFSET)
{
    List<All_Post> allPostDescList = new ArrayList<All_Post>();
    String selectQuery = "select * from  " + Table_AllPost_Table + " where  ActiveStatus = '1' AND Status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY ActionDate DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET "+OFFSET; //ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            All_Post allPostDesc = new All_Post();
            allPostDesc.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ALL_ACT_ID")));
            allPostDesc.setStrActiveStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActiveStatus")));
            allPostDesc.setStrActivityId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActivityId")));
            allPostDesc.setStrRemark(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Remark")));
            allPostDesc.setStrProfilePic(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProfilePICURL")));
            allPostDesc.setStringInspectorname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("inspectorName")));
            allPostDesc.setStrNotationNo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("HashTag")));
            allPostDesc.setStrShortName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Type")));
            allPostDesc.setStrUserId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UserId")));
            allPostDesc.setStrvessel_Id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VesselId")));

            String strSqliteDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActionDate"));

            if (strSqliteDate != null && !strSqliteDate.isEmpty()) {
                String result = "";
                Date date1 = null;
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                try {
                    date1 = dateFormat.parse(strSqliteDate);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date1);
                SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                result = printFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                //Log.e("result = ","==========>"+result);
                allPostDesc.setActiondate(result);
            }

            allPostDesc.setStrStarFlag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StarFlag")));
            allPostDesc.setStrDownLoadStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status")));
            allPostDescList.add(allPostDesc);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return allPostDescList;
}

    }
```

Comment: post whole code of db helper class

Comment: can you post your error log too?

Comment: Exactly which line has the exception?

Comment: I have edit above post and post whole code of db helper class. Please help me out. I face this problem lot of time .

Comment: Also post the usage of this class in your question.